# How to run a .py file from iOS using Swift

Tags: python, ios, swift, selenium

I have a Python project for web automatization using Selenium. As I do not always have access to my computer, I would like to be able to run it from my iPhone. Is it possible to run a .py file from a Swift app on iOS? I would appreciate code samples since I am a beginner but simply pointing me in the right direction would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: are you asking whether you can actually run python within your app or asking how to make a web request to your hosted python project?

Comment: you can create a api for this at backend and use that in your app to do your tasks !

Answer (score 1):

1) You need some backend application running on your PC;

2) backend application must have some Web API for managing Selenium application;

3) From iOS app you send http-request to API using Alamofire or any other solution.